# Versioning in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have a usecases where functions written in Python needs to be versioned (for example a Feature computation for ML model).

Say Function1 has two copies, one is version1 and the second is version2 and you want both to be available for consumption i.e you can invoke any copy of the function by specifying the function name and version (of course both versions are different from each other)

Question:

1. Can we serve multiple versions of the same Python function under one application? What would be the best way to achieve it ?
2. Say if someone adds a new function Function2, do you need to restart the Python application so Function2 is also available for consumption? (In Java world, you will restart the app to reload the latest jar in RAM)

Thanks

Comment: First, don't ask multiple, completely separate, questions in a single question.

Comment: Since your question isn't really answerable as-is and will probably be closed, here's some comments. For 1., the simplest solution is to just give the functions different names: `function1_v1` and `function1_v2`. You could get fancier and, say, put them in a list, so someone can use `function1[0]` and `function1[1]` and `function1[-1]` to get the latest version. But, without some more concrete example of what you're trying to do, it's hard to say whether that's worth doing.

Comment: For 2., yes, normally you need to restart the application. There are various tricks to get around that, however. For example, some web frameworks use a helper application that launches the real application as a child, then monitors the files; if one of them changes, it asks the child to gracefully quit, then relaunches it. So, to the developer, this looks a lot like the code is magically self-updating Smalltalk-style, even though it really isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, essentially I am trying to build a feature generation engine. So before running a model, you will compute features. Feature is a basic computation/calculation, where each feature can take input and return a number or Boolean. Each feature can be versioned, for example tomorrow you can change the implementation of one function. Clients will request features by name and version through http

Comment: One more trick: If you design a "plugin" system, you can make your app watch the plugin directory for new files, then try to import and register them. This doesn't allow you to change or remove old functions on the fly, but does allow you to add new ones on the fly (by putting them in a new plugin module and dropping it into the directory).

Comment: Features should be implemented in Python, because data scientists love Python :)

Comment: Removed wrong "ml" tag.

Comment: Part of the reason data scientists love Python is that it _doesn't_ try to have every feature in the world. There's a lot less to learn, a lot less to keep straight if you go back and forth between Python and R every few months, and very few complicated interactions between features to make it hard to figure out what's going on. And yet, it still has almost every feature you actually want most of the time. That's a tough balancing act, and there's two mailing list full of experts arguing the pros and cons of every change to keep it balanced.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we serve multiple versions of the same Python function under one application?

Yes, you can, but there is no single "standard" way to do it - you have many possibilities for rolling your own.

> What would be the best way to achieve it?

In theory, one reasonably clean approach would be to make use of the Python's packaging and [entry points](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/) system.

Wrap each implementation of your function into a separate package (e.g. `featureextractor_A`, `featureextractor_B`).  Within `setup.py` of any package which is meant to provide (in general one or more) implementations, have an entry point specification of the form:

```
entry_points="""
    [my.feature.extractor]
    feature_1=featureextractor_A:function_A
    feature_2=featureextractor_A:function_B
""",
```

You can then list all of the "feature extractors" currently available in the system from all the packages as follows:

```
from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points
for entry_point in iter_entry_points(group='my.feature.provider', name=None):
    ... do something with entry_point ...
```

Note again, that this is not the only way to manage such a registry of functions. You may just as well list your "pluggable" functions in your application-specific config file or a database table, for example, thus side-stepping the `pkg_resources` subsystem (which can [slow down the startup time of your app considerably](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/510)).

> do you need to restart the Python application so Function2 is also available for consumption

It depends on how you implement the whole system. In the entry-point-based solution, proposed above, the list of all available entry points is constructed by `pkg_resources` when it is first imported at the startup of your application, hence you would need to restart or force a re-scan in some way to make use of newly installed packages without restarting.

In general, though, whenever you install new packages to your Python's system path, you do not need to restart in order to use them. Hence, if you maintain your own registry you can decide whether you want to "re-scan" it regularly, or simply always refer to some persistent state each time you need to invoke a "pluggable" function (the downside here being an overhead of a DB request on each invocation).